# Take Input from a form and save it to an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am having trouble trying to convert this into an array. I don't fully understand how to take input from a form and save it in an array.

**My project states: Do NOT save the input in a set of variables and then put those in an array.
Use the array as your collection of data saving variables. (That is what a data
structure is for.)**

I have looked for the last 2 hours trying to find something to help me. I have to do this project in JavaScript, but keep finding jquery and I'm not quite sure on how to convert it to Javascript

Any suggestions on how I can take the form input and save it in an array?

This is only a little bit of my project. I just took the first function and the HTML that is attached to the function.

Code in the snippet.

```js
   function getID() {
       var studentID = new Array();
       studentID = document.forms["getFormInfo"]["txtStudentID"].value;
       var numberOnly = /^[0-9]+$/;

       //Checks for a null/blank within Student ID: field.
       if (studentID.length == 0) {
         document.getElementById('divAllField').style.display = '';
         document.forms["getFormInfo"]["txtStudentID"].focus();
         return false;
       } //End of if statement
       else {
         if (studentID.length == 8 && studentID.match(numberOnly)) {
           //Run the next function
           getFirstName();
         } //End of else/if statement
         else {
           //Show Error Message
           document.getElementById('divStudentID').style.display = "";
           //Focus on input field with the error.
           document.forms["getFormInfo"]["txtStudentID"].focus();
         } //end of else/if/else statement
       } //End of else statement
     } //End of function getID()
```

```css
   h1 {
     text-align: center;
     color: teal;
   }
   table {
     border-spacing: 8px;
     border: 2px solid black;
     text-align: justify;
   }
   th {
     text-align: center;
     padding: 8px;
     color: blue;
     font-size: 125%;
   }
   td {
     padding: 5px;
   }
   input,
   select {
     width: 200px;
     border: 1px solid #000;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     height: 22px;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   input {
     text-indent: 2px;
   }
   label {
     float: left;
     min-width: 115px;
   }
   div {
     padding: 3px;
     color: red;
     font-size: 80%;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Begining of the header -->

</head>
<!-- End of the header -->

<body>
  <!-- Everything in the <body> </body> displays on the webpage -->

  <form id="getFormInfo">
    <!-- Creates a form with an ID -->
    <table id="tableInfo">
      <!-- Creates a table within the form -->

      <!-- Creates a table header within the form and table -->
      <th>User Information</th>


      <!-- Error Message for all fields if they are null/blank -->
      <tr>
        <td><strong><div id="divAllField" style="display: none;">
              Please make sure all input boxes are filled out.
              </div></strong>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <!-- Student ID Input -->
      <tr>
        <td><strong><label>Student ID:</label></strong>
          <input type="text" name="txtStudentID" maxlength="8" placeholder="8 Digit ID" value="00149371" required>
          <!-- Error Message for Student ID -->
          <strong><div id="divStudentID" style="display: none;">
              Please enter your 8 Digit Student ID. (Whole Numbers Only)</br>
              Example: 00123456
              </div></strong>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tfoot>
        <td>
          <input type="button" onclick="getID();" value="Submit">
      </tfoot>
      </td>

    </table>
    <!-- End of tableInfo -->
  </form>
  <!-- End of getInfo -->

</body>

</html>
```

**Anyone know how I can save the input from the form and save it into an array?**

*Please help, I've been working on this project for over 10 hours.*

Answer (score 0):

Use the **[`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** function to add items to the array.

```
function getID() {
   var studentID = [];
   var tstStudentIdVal = document.forms["getFormInfo"]["txtStudentID"].value
   studentID.push(tstStudentIdVal);
   var numberOnly = /^[0-9]+$/;

   //Checks for a null/blank within Student ID: field.
   if (tstStudentIdVal.length == 0) {
     document.getElementById('divAllField').style.display = '';
     document.forms["getFormInfo"]["txtStudentID"].focus();
     return false;
   } //End of if statement
   else {
     if (tstStudentIdVal.length == 8 && tstStudentIdVal.match(numberOnly)) {
       //Run the next function
       getFirstName();
     } //End of else/if statement
     else {
       //Show Error Message
       document.getElementById('divStudentID').style.display = "";
       //Focus on input field with the error.
       document.forms["getFormInfo"]["txtStudentID"].focus();
     } //end of else/if/else statement
   } //End of else statement
 } //End of function getID()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most elegant solution is to use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) to get a nodeList of all your inputs, then [use a combination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#calling_map_on_non-array_objects) of [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to translate the array of inputs into an array of your own design.

In the snippet below, the resulting array has objects each which have a `name` and `value`, which come directly from the text inputs in your form (your question isn't quite clear on how the resulting array should look).

```js
function getID() {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#getFormInfo input[type='text']");
  var array = Array.from(inputs)
    .map(item => ({ name: item.name,  value: item.value }));
  console.log(array);
}
```

```html
<form id="getFormInfo">
  <input type="text" name="txtStudentID" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="firstName" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="lastName" value="" />
  <input type="button" onclick="getID();" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: It might also work to just call `[].map.call(nodes, function(item) { ... });`.

Comment: @ScottKaye absolutely

Comment: True, I semi-recently discovered that trick and have been trying to apply it everywhere :)

Comment: @ScottKaye I went back and forth a couple times and decided I really like your implementation with `.call()`. I edited the answer to use the syntax you suggested.

Comment: @mplungjan, feel free to suggest an edit--the original answer was posted almost a decade ago